# What would be the best way to test a flow (cross controllers)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

There is a certain flow within our application that makes separate calls with related data. These are in different controllers, but interact with the same user.

We're trying to build a test to confirm that the full flow works as expected. We've built individual tests for the constituent parts, but want a test for the full flow.

E.g., we have a user who checks in to work (checkin) and then builds a widget (widgetize). We have methods that will filter our users between who have checked in, and who have widgetized (and checked in). We can build little objects with FactoryGirl to ensure that the filter works, but we want a test that will have a user check in, another user check in, and the second one widgetize so that we can confirm that our filtering methods only capture the users we want it to capture.

My first thought was to build an rspec test that simply made a direct call to checkin from the widgetize spec, and then confirm the filter methods -- but I discovered that rspec does not allow cross controller calls (or at least I could not figure out how to make it work; posts and gets to that controller were not working). Also, people told me this was very bad practice.

How should I go about testing this?

Comment: Isn't this just a standard integration test?

Comment: ya, sounds like an integtration test.  I recommend using capybara gem to simulate the user flow exactly as you have described.

Answer (score 0):

This article goes over how you can use request-specs to go through integration tests fairly well.

http://everydayrails.com/2012/04/24/testing-series-rspec-requests.html

Basically you want to use a gem like capybara so you can simulate user input and get your tests to run through your app and check to see if everything is going as you expect it to.

Comment: Using capybara in request specs has been deprecated.  The current approach is to use [Feature Specs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/feature-specs/feature-spec)